# Может ли бот автоматически присоединяться к чату в телеграмме?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Использую библиотеку telebot, пытался использовать метод:

bot.join_chat_by_link (Пример аргумента: `"https://t.me/+<ссылка_на_чат>"`)

Пишет, что нет данного атрибута . В чем может заключаться проблема?

Вот сама ошибка:

AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'join_chat_by_link'